# how to calculate maximum showable size of an image

Tags: android

I am trying to show an image in its maximum resolution. So far I manage my app to work, but what I did is temporal.

```
    private Bitmap loadImage() {
    String imgName=resolveImageName();      
    if(!imgName.equals("")){                    
        String imgN=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ImageChooserActivity.GENFACE_PATH+imgName;
        Log.d("LOAD IMAGE", imgN);
        BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();         
        op.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgN, op);

        return bm;
    }
    return null;
```

I tried to calculate inSamplesize using the following code, but I always get 1, and that is not a valid value. The maximum value for the image that I am using for inSampleSize is 2 (image resolution 2048x2048, maximum resolution supported 1944x2592 so de image is resized to 1/2 972x1296)

```
private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options){
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int maxHeight = dm.heightPixels;                
    int maxWidth = dm.widthPixels;      
    int photoHeight=options.outHeight;              
    int photoWidth=options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;       
    if (photoHeight > maxHeight || photoWidth > maxWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = photoHeight / 2;
        final int halfWidth = photoWidth / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > maxHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > maxWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("inSampleSize: "+inSampleSize);
    return inSampleSize;

}
```

I need to calculate this in order to get my app working in different screens, 
in advance, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the code with a debugger yet to see how it executes? It seems to be doing exactly what is intended by the code, if you need to modify it you should figure out how to make modifications that will work for you.

This part....

```
while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > maxHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > maxWidth) {
   inSampleSize *= 2;
}
```

increases `inSampleSize` only when `halfHeight` and `halfWidth` are greater than the provided maximums. So if `halfHeight` = 972 and `halfWidth` = 1296 when using your example parameters both are less than maximums and will return `inSampleSize = 1`. The loop never executes.

If you want to break this convention then perhaps changing it to a do-while loop is more appropriate?

Comment: I debug it, the first thing is that I got as maxHeight 1184 and max width = 720. But I know is 1944x2592, this because when I tried to show the image whitout performing the rezise, I got an error , and the maximum resolution. So, how can I get the resolution ? btw: thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return a sample size so that the final image is always bigger than the requirement(and at the same time making it as small as possible).
If you want your image smaller than the requirement, but at the same time as big as possible, change this:

```
final int halfHeight = photoHeight;
final int halfWidth = photoWidth;
```